# How to post to external url from rails app without using form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, payment-gateway

I am able to post to my payment gateway using a html form. But I got a new requirement. Now, On click of "payment" button, i have to validate whether item is still available for purchase and if available then automatically post the payment form to gateway.

So to say, I want to execute some rails controller code on button click and then want to redirect to an external url ( payment gateway ) with params if validation succeed.

I read, it is not possible to post using redirect_to in rails. It is also not possible to post using ajax to external url. How should i achieve it ?

Comment: This is how i handled it. On the checkout page - instead of generating payment form, i generated a link to "payment" action with remote: true. Then I validated all the checks on "payment" action. Redirected to home page for the cases when validations failed and rendered payment.js.erb for the case when payment succeed. 

Wrote a new partial "_payment_form.html.erb" for payment form. Now in payment.js.erb, I rendered payment_form on the fly and added it to some div and submitted the form using jquery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Ruby’s [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) like this:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/search")
params = {"foo" => "value one", "bar" => "value two"}


# Shortcut way
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)


# With more control
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(params)
response = http.request(request)


puts response.code             # => 200
puts response.body             # => The body (HTML, JSON, etc)
```

Comment: I actually, wanted to redirect to my payment gateway after successful validation. I did it by posting (remote: true ) using ajax and then doing required validation on controller's action (payment) and rendering payment.js.erb

Then rendered a form in payment.js.erb and submitted it to payment gateway using jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me with my refund API call where I wanted to capture the response in application itself.